# Div to fade but not header and footer

Tags: jquery, fade

EDIT:  I updated the js to the example listed below by 'Front End Buy' and now my links do not work.  Ive edited my original post to show what I am now using.  Any idea why the links are no longer working?

Im trying to get my main content to fade without the header and footer fading.  below is my code.  below is my code that i have set up.  I do have an external call to the jquery library in my header.  Thanks

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var linkLocation = null;
  $("#content").hide().fadeIn(2000);
  $("a.transition").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $("#content").fadeOut(1000, function() {
      redirectPage();
    });      
  });
  function redirectPage() {
    window.location = linkLocation;
  }
});
</script>


<body>
<div id="content_wrapper">

    <div id="header">

        <div id="logo"></div>           

        <div id="nav">
            <ul id="nav" class="nav">
                <li id="home"><a href="index.html" title="" class="transition">Home</a></li>            
                <li id="about"><a href="about.html" title="About Us" class="transition">About Us</a></li>
                <li id="contact"><a href="contact.html" title="Contact Us" class="transition">Contact Us</a></li>                   
            </ul>
        </div> 

    <!--End Main Nav-->           

    </div> 
    <!-- End of Content Header -->
    <div id="content">  
    some text etc...
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you use the proper selector, as in `$('#content')` that should work fine ?

Comment: Also there is no reason at all to query multiple times for #content since it is not dynamical content. And .hide handles the display property, you don't need to change it to none.

Answer (score 0):

`content` is the element's **ID** so you have to prefix the selector with a `#`, like this:

```
$('#content').hide().fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: When I change my script to the following my links no longer work.



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 
    $("#content").hide().fadeIn(2000);
 
    $("a.transition").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("#content").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
    });
         
    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
</script>

Comment: You need to create a jsFiddle if you're serious about getting help with this.

Answer (score 0):

There are few key things missing with your JS. First, make sure you add `#` to the front of your ids. Second, you want to create a `variable` for the link location so it knows what that is in the second function. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var linkLocation = null;  // Create a variable for the link location.
  $("#content").hide().fadeIn(2000);
  $("a.transition").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action from happening.
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $("#content").fadeOut(1000, function() { // on complete, redirect the page.
      redirectPage();
    });      
  });
  function redirectPage() {
    window.location = linkLocation;
  }
});
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Johvl) for it in action.

Comment: I edited my original code to what Front End Guy suggested.  Now my links no longer work.